# ComboBox transparency issue how to prevent it, in wp8.1 C#

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

When i opened comboBox with 4 items, It is working properly but it is showing if it has any controls behind of comboBox when it open ,those controls also visible.How to prevent and i didn't add any background color

[ComboBox before opening image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE6Fr.png)

[ComboBox After opening image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy45b.png)

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbBoxPriority" Margin="157,323,17,372" Tapped="cmbBoxPriority_Tapped" Opacity="1" Background="#FFD8CFCF"   Foreground="Black"  >
                    <x:String>Low</x:String>
                    <x:String>Medium</x:String>
                    <x:String>High</x:String>
                    <x:String>Critical</x:String>
                </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Can any one suggest to above problem.I stuck

Answer (score 0):

You did not insert the items properly. You just inserted 4 strings into the `ComboBox` instead of 4 `ComboBox` items. Change  `<x:String>` for `<ComboBoxItem>`.